# SQL AVG() Returning the wrong result for 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am writing a query that is supposed to give me a `count()` and three `avg()`'s. The `count()` works just fine, but the `avg()` functions are returning erroneous results.  The data I am working with looks like this:

```
MD Name |    PT | Med Staff | LOS | DRG Bench | LOS - Bench
MCP     | 12345 | Ortho SX  |  5  |    4      |       1
MCP     | 25879 | Ortho SX  |  3  |    5      |      -2
MCP     | 98556 | Ortho SX  |  4  |    5      |      -1
...
```

***My Desired Output is:***

```
MD Name | # PT | Med Staff | Avg LOS | Avg DRG Bench | AVG LOS - Bench
MCP     |   3  | Ortho SX  |    4    |       4.66    |       0
```

I am getting incorrect results for the averages. I have one case in particular where I have the following:

```
MD Name | LOS    | Bench  | LOS - Bench
MCP     | 2.0000 | 1.8000 |    0.2000
MCP     | 1.0000 | 1.7000 |   -0.7000
MCP     | 25.0000| 4.9000 |   20.1000
MCP     | 4.0000 | 2.2000 |    1.8000
```

For and AVG LOS I am getting 9.000000 instead of 8.000000, for the AVG Bench I am getting 2.780000 instead of 2.65 and for the LOS-Bench I am getting 6.220000 instead of 5.35, these are significant differences and I must be correct to two decimal places.

Here is the SQL I am using, SQL Server 2008

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDATE DATETIME

SET @STARTDATE = '2013-05-01'
SET @ENDATE = '2013-05-31'

SELECT DISTINCT pv.pract_rpt_name AS 'PHYSICIAN'
, COUNT(DISTINCT vr.pt_id) AS '# PTS' 
--, pv.spclty_desc AS 'SPECIALTY'
, pv.med_staff_dept AS 'MED STAFF'
, AVG(vr.len_of_stay) AS 'LOS'
, AVG(vr.drg_std_days_stay) AS 'DRG LOS BENCH'
, AVG(vr.len_of_stay - vr.drg_std_days_stay) AS 'LOS - DRG BENCH'

FROM smsmir.vst_rpt vr
LEFT OUTER JOIN smsmir.pyr_plan pp <-- removed and fixed
ON vr.pt_id = pp.pt_id <-- removed and fixed
JOIN smsdss.pract_dim_v pv
ON vr.adm_pract_no = pv.src_pract_no

WHERE vr.adm_dtime BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDATE
AND vr.vst_type_cd = 'I'
AND pv.spclty_desc != 'NO DESCRIPTION'
--AND pv.spclty_desc NOT LIKE 'HOSPITALIST%'
AND vr.drg_std_days_stay IS NOT NULL
AND pv.pract_rpt_name != '?'
AND pv.orgz_cd = 's0x0'
AND pv.med_staff_dept IN (
'INTERNAL MEDICINE',
'FAMILY PRACTICE',
'SURGERY'
)
GROUP BY pv.pract_rpt_name, pv.med_staff_dept
ORDER BY pv.med_staff_dept, AVG(vr.len_of_stay - vr.drg_std_days_stay)DESC
```

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: What is the datatype of the source columns?

Comment: You have a OUTER JOIN to a table that doesn't appear to be used at any point in the query. Try removing that clause and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: I'd say that the query probably gets more rows than you think. `Count` is probably correct because of `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @Rikalous it was that OUTER JOIN, why it was in there I can't remember now...Now I have to think about why it was in my original query, but thanks, that fixed it right up, post as a solution so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OUTER JOIN you have in the query may be affecting the number of rows that the AVG function is operating over. If you don't need it (and I can't see anywhere where that table is referenced elsewhere in your query) try removing it.

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility is presence of the NULL's in the rows in your table selects...
if there is a null column the AVG will ignore it, instead of counting it...

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDATE DATETIME

SET @STARTDATE = '2013-05-01'
SET @ENDATE = '2013-05-31'

SELECT DISTINCT pv.pract_rpt_name AS 'PHYSICIAN'
, COUNT(DISTINCT vr.pt_id) AS '# PTS' 
--, pv.spclty_desc AS 'SPECIALTY'
, pv.med_staff_dept AS 'MED STAFF'
, AVG(ISNULL(vr.len_of_stay,0)) AS 'LOS'
, AVG(ISNULL(vr.drg_std_days_stay,0)) AS 'DRG LOS BENCH'
, AVG(ISNULL((vr.len_of_stay - vr.drg_std_days_stay),0)) AS 'LOS - DRG BENCH'

FROM smsmir.vst_rpt vr
LEFT OUTER JOIN smsmir.pyr_plan pp
ON vr.pt_id = pp.pt_id
JOIN smsdss.pract_dim_v pv
ON vr.adm_pract_no = pv.src_pract_no

WHERE vr.adm_dtime BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDATE
AND vr.vst_type_cd = 'I'
AND pv.spclty_desc != 'NO DESCRIPTION'
--AND pv.spclty_desc NOT LIKE 'HOSPITALIST%'
AND vr.drg_std_days_stay IS NOT NULL
AND pv.pract_rpt_name != '?'
AND pv.orgz_cd = 's0x0'
AND pv.med_staff_dept IN (
'INTERNAL MEDICINE',
'FAMILY PRACTICE',
'SURGERY'
)
GROUP BY pv.pract_rpt_name, pv.med_staff_dept
ORDER BY pv.med_staff_dept, AVG(vr.len_of_stay - vr.drg_std_days_stay)DESC
```